# TypeError: Cannot find function getDataRange in object

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to create a script that will search the entire of workbook "A" and workbook "B" for a duplicate value, and then delete the row containing the duplicate from its location in workbook "A".

However when running the script I get error "TypeError: Cannot find function getDataRange in object" back at me and I cannot figure out why.

The script I am working on is below:

```
   function deleteRowInSpreadsheet1() { 
var s1 =SpreadsheetApp.openById("1pxWr3jOYZbcwlFR7igpSWa9BKCa2tTeliE8FwFCRTcQ").getSheets();
var s2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("18jLxZlge_UFkdTjlO6opuDk1VKeezhEPLe9B7n1OfQs").getSheets(); 
var values1 = s1.getDataRange().getValues();
var values2 = s2.getDataRange().getValues();
var resultArray = [];
for(var n in values2){
var keep = true
for(var p in values1){
  if( values1[n][0] == values1[p][0] && values2[n][1] == values1[p][1]){
    keep=false ; break ;
  }
}
if(keep){ resultArray.push(values2[n])};
}
s1.clear()
s1.getRange(1,1,resultArray.length,resultArray[0].length).setValues(resultArray);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling `getSheets()`, which returns an Array of sheets. So you'll need to loop through each sheet and then call `getDataRange()`.

As an example:

```
var s1 =SpreadsheetApp.openById("1pxWr3jOYZbcwlFR7igpSWa9BKCa2tTeliE8FwFCRTcQ").getSheets();
for (var i=0; i<s1.length; i++) {
  var values = s1[i].getDataRange().getValues();
}
```

Then, of course, use those values where you need them.

Comment: Perfect, got me past that problem, but now its throwing up another, more work to be done yet I think.

Answer (score 1):

In the lines

```
var s1 =SpreadsheetApp.openById("RTcQ").getSheets();
var s2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("7fQs").getSheets();
```

You use the `.getSheets()` method which is returning an object containing all the sheets in that spreadsheet. You cannot get the data range of this object.

Instead, you should use `.getActiveSheet()` or `.getSheetByName()`

```
var s1 =SpreadsheetApp.openById("RTcQ").getSheetByName('Sheet1');
var s2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("7fQs").getSheetByName('Sheet2');
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply,  My only problem with that is there are always new sheets being added by numerous users each day, which means I would have to change the script each day to add and remove sheet names from the script. What I am trying to achieve is to ask for a list of sheets, and then search the sheets for duplicate values on another workbook and then delete from the first one.

Comment: Sorry, I completely missed the 'entire' part of your OP!