# TypeError: Cannot find function clear in object (google script)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to create a script that will search the entire of workbook "A" and workbook "B" for a duplicate value, and then delete the row containing the duplicate from its location in workbook "A".

However when running the script I get error "TypeError: Cannot find function clear in object" back at me, and I really cannot figure out why.

I will try and explain in more detail what I am trying to achieve.

Spreadsheet 1, contains details of all my open order waiting to be supplied to a customer, the tab names can change daily but most tabs are formatted the same, apart from 2 tabs that will never change names.

Spreadsheet 2, contains deatails of orders that have been supplied and invoiced.

Therefore once I have inputted a ticket no. into Spreadsheet 2, I would then have to search spreadsheet 2 for the ticket no. and delete the row as it is no longer an open order. I would like a script that does this task for me.

The script I am working on is below.

```
function deleteRowInSpreadsheet1() { 
      var s1 =SpreadsheetApp.openById("1pxWr3jOYZbcwlFR7igpSWa9BKCa2tTeliE8FwFCRTcQ").getSheets();
      for (var i=0; i<s1.length; i++) {
        var values1 = s1[i].getDataRange().getValues();
        var s2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("18jLxZlge_UFkdTjlO6opuDk1VKeezhEPLe9B7n1OfQs").getSheets(); 
        for (var i=0; i<s1.length; i++) {
          var values2 = s2[i].getDataRange().getValues();
          var resultArray = [];
          for(var n in values2){
            var keep = true
            for(var p in values1){
              if( values1[n][0] == values1[p][0] && values2[n][1] == values1[p][1]){
                keep=false;
                break;
              }
            }
            if(keep){ 
              resultArray.push(values2[n]);
            }
          }
          s1.clear()
          s1.getRange(1,1,resultArray.length,resultArray[0].length).setValues(resultArray); 
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: getSheets() returns an array of sheets.There is no clear() method in a Javascript 1.6 Array.  [Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Comment: Same cause (duplicate of) as https://stackoverflow.com/q/49579331/9337071

Comment: @tehhowch different question, different problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: Cannot find function getDataRange in object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49579331/typeerror-cannot-find-function-getdatarange-in-object)

Answer (score 0):

## Regarding the specific error

> However when running the script I get error "TypeError: Cannot find function clear in object" back at me, and I really cannot figure out why.

The code line

`var s1 =SpreadsheetApp.openById("1pxWr3jOYZbcwlFR7igpSWa9BKCa2tTeliE8FwFCRTcQ").getSheets();`

Assigns an array of sheets objects to `s1` but `clear` isn't a array method.

---

It's worth to note that the code on the question has other programming errors like:

1. nesting for loops a un use the same variable `i` as the iterator for both.
2. having `var s2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("18jLxZlge_UFkdTjlO6opuDk1VKeezhEPLe9B7n1OfQs").getSheets();` inside a for loop makes the script inefficient

## Regarding your goal

It looks to me that you tried to adapt the code from the [answer by Serge insas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22010900/1595451) to [Google Script: Delete row if a value in it exists in another sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22008331/1595451)

```js
function deleteRowInSheet1() {
  var s1 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1RxtFWZJRWxgW-zUM6S-dvZ0yFe-G2DGJFWI3gAt-1T0").getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var s2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1RxtFWZJRWxgW-zUM6S-dvZ0yFe-G2DGJFWI3gAt-1T0").getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  var values1 = s1.getDataRange().getValues();
  var values2 = s2.getDataRange().getValues();
  var resultArray = [];
  for (var n in values1) {
    var keep = true
    for (var p in values2) {
      if (values1[n][0] == values2[p][0] && values1[n][1] == values2[p][1]) {
        keep = false;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (keep) {
      resultArray.push(values1[n])
    };
  }
  s1.clear()
  s1.getRange(1, 1, resultArray.length, resultArray[0].length).setValues(resultArray);
}
```

The design error was to remove the getSheetByName assuming that this will make the function work for every sheet on both spreadsheets. Instead you have to include a loop for each spreadsheet to iterate through all the sheets of each one. Something like the following could work (I didn't tested it)

```js
function deleteRowInSpreadsheet1() {
  var ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.openById(/*add here your spreadsheet 1 id*/);
  var ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById(/*add here your spreadsheet 2 id*/);
  //
  for (var l in ss1) {
    for(var m in ss2 {
      var values1 = ss1[l].getDataRange().getValues();
      var values2 = ss2[m].getDataRange().getValues();
      var resultArray = [];
      for (var n in values1) {
        var keep = true;
        for (var p in values2) {
          if (values1[n][0] == values2[p][0] && values1[n][1] == values2[p][1]) {
            keep = false;
            break;
          }
        }
        if (keep) {
          resultArray.push(values1[n]);
        };
      }
      s1.clear();
      s1.getRange(1, 1, resultArray.length, resultArray[0].length).setValues(resultArray);
    } // closes l loop
  }  // closes m loop
}
```